# Method calling a singular optional param and keep the other optional param at default

Tags: ruby, methods

I have a method:

```
def my_method(id,raise_error=true,validate=false)
  ...
end
```

How can I call this method using only the second optional parameter?

I tried:

```
my_method(20,,false)
```

Would it be better here to use an options hash?

**Update:**

I would also be able to call the method setting `raise_error = false` and keep `validate` at default value `false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it this way. Instead, you can use keyword arguments:

```
def my_method(id, raise_error: true, validate: false)
  #  ...
end
```

and call it with only `validate` argument:

```
my_method(20, validate: true)
```

Comment: That looks like what I want. I would need to use symbols here right?

Comment: Define your method as `def my_method(id, *args)`. Here, your ***args** will be array of params

Comment: @mahatmanich This construction is not a hash with symbol as keys, but other construct - keword arguments (or named arguments).

Comment: @MarekLipka Sorry, I was confused about **arguments**, I thought you meant ***args** as posted by Dipak

Comment: @MarekLipka Do you have a pointer to ruby doc where this kind of method declaration is documented?

Comment: @mahatmanich Here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can also use optional hash here:

Below is argument calling herarchy that might help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest passing nil to the first optional parameter

```
my_method(20, nil, false)
```

Comment: I would want to keep raise_error to be default as ```true``` if it is not used.

Comment: `nil` is nothing, if you can avoid it, you should avoid it, no need to work with nothing.

Comment: he wants that parameter in the method, but he also wants to call the method with out that parameter in a particular case

Comment: I want to keep the default set in the optional parameters and I want to call the method interchangeably to call either optional parameters. btw I did not downvote you.